# String returns tags and not formatted text

Tags: java, android, string

Code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(String.format("<b>%s. %s</b> %s", Integer.toString(id), name, description));
derp.setText(sb.toString());
```

Returns:

< b>id. name< /b> description

Wanted outcome:

**id. name** description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

`derp.setText(Html.fromHtml(sb.toString()));`

Comment: well, it works but it seems like it removes all '\n' in description. Any ideas?

Comment: @Anton You can replace occurrences of `'\n'` in your source string with `<br>` to accomplish the same effect.

Comment: That's not really possible, or maybe i'll make a replace function. I tried do Html.fromHtml(sb.toString()+description) and it removes the bold, do u know why?

Comment: @Anton `description.replace("\n", "<br>");` is all it takes to replace those characters. :)

Comment: Ah, that did the trick, didn't knew about replace() so thanks :)